# Is there any aqueous solution (or simple method) to remove trace level of sulfur dioxide/nitrogen monoxide and nitrogen dioxide in a gas stream?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, home-experiment

I need to generate pure gas from a gas stream which is free of $\ce{SO2}$/$\ce{NO}$/$\ce{NO2}.$ The air is already pretreated by activated carbon and purafil. However, I can't find any solution for removing trace level of this pollutants. I find that many solutions of capturing for large scale like flue gas. However, it is not suitable for trace level (1–10 ppb).

I know $\ce{O3}$ can react with $\ce{NO}$ to $\ce{NO2}$. However, as I mentioned, I need the gas stream free of $\ce{NO}$ and $\ce{NO2}$ simultaneously. So, converting $\ce{NO}$ to $\ce{NO2}$ is not the answer.

Comment: Can you describe what are you doing? Which pure gas and how it is being generated? Is this a science project?

Comment: You may have the gas mixture bubble in a NaOH solution, or wash it through a column with flowing NaOH solution at countercurrent. SO2 and NO2 will be dissolved. And if some O2 is also present, NO will soon be oxidized into NO2, and then dissolved.

Comment: If you cool it what will liquify first and last?

Comment: As I mentioned, I need the gas stream free of NO and NO2 simultaneously. So, converting NO to NO2 is not the answer. Thanks. @Maurice

Comment: I need to purify the gas stream to zero ppb of SO2/NO/NOX. The gas is pre-treated by purafil and activated carbon. The flow rate is around 5 lpm. @DrMoishe Pippik

Comment: You can convert NO in NO2 with O2, and then wash the gas with NaOH solution : 2 NaOH + 2NO2 -->  NaNO2 + NaNO3 + H2O

Comment: You could also use a gas mask containing some active charcoal, which has pores big enough to adsorb impurities like NO2.

Answer (score 1):

**Removal of $\ce{SO2, NO2}$ from solution**

As mentioned by Maurice, you can remove $\ce{SO2, NO2}$ by bubbling the mixture bubble through NaOH or KOH solution, or washing it through a column with flowing NaOH or KOH solution at countercurrent.

**Removal of $\ce{NO}$ from solution**

You can bubble the mixture through [$\ce{aq.FeSO4}$ solution](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/i260067a019).
I remember doing this in eudiometry experiments.